# How to make a object with the all field value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want variantsObject should be like below please help me**

> {
> "6gb,red": {
> "price": "10000",
> "qty": "5"
> },
> "4gb,red": {
> "price": "3000",
> "qty": "3"
> }
> }

**I have made this code to make that things but i am getting the last onBlur value...attached the code below please look and help me**

**page variantsForm**
const VariantForm = props => {

```
    const [variantsObject, setVariantsObject] = useState([]);

    const getPrice = (value, item) => {
        const newVariants = {
            [item]: {
                price: value
            }
        }
        setVariantsObject(() => {
            return Object.assign({} , variantsObject, newVariants)
        });
    }
    const getQty = (value, item) => {
        const newVariants = {
            [item]: {
                qty: value
            }
        };
        setVariantsObject(() => Object.assign({}, variantsObject, newVariants));
    };
    const getSku = (value, item) => {
        const newVariants = {
            [item]: {
                sku: value
            }
        };
        setVariantsObject(() => Object.assign({}, variantsObject, newVariants));
    };

    console.log(variantsObject)

    const variants = [
        [
            "6gb",
            "red"
        ],
        [
            "4gb",
            "red"
        ]
    ]

    return (
                <Table className="table-default variantTable" responsive>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>Variant</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Sku</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        {variants.map((item, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>
                                    <input
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        className="vCBox"
                                        id={item.toString()}
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {item
                                        .toString()
                                        .split(",")
                                        .join(" / ")}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="$0.00"
                                        name="variantPrice"
                                        onBlur={e => getPrice(e.target.value, item.toString())}
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="number"
                                        placeholder="0"
                                        name="variantQty"
                                        onBlur={e => getQty(e.target.value, item.toString())}
                                    />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder=""
                                        name="variantSku"
                                        onBlur={e => getSku(e.target.value, item.toString())}
                                    />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
    )
};

export default VariantForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Object.assign` does a shallow merge and not a deep merge you need to first, read previous value of target object from state, and then assign new property to object, like this:

```js
const VariantForm = (props) => {
  const [variantsObject, setVariantsObject] = React.useState([]);

  const getPrice = (value, item) => {
    const newVariants = {
      [item]: {
        ...variantsObject[item],
        price: value,
      },
    };
    setVariantsObject(() => {
      return Object.assign({}, variantsObject, newVariants);
    });
  };
  const getQty = (value, item) => {
    const newVariants = {
      [item]: {
        ...variantsObject[item],
        qty: value,
      },
    };
    setVariantsObject(() => Object.assign({}, variantsObject, newVariants));
  };
  const getSku = (value, item) => {
    const newVariants = {
      [item]: {
        ...variantsObject[item],
        sku: value,
      },
    };
    setVariantsObject(() => Object.assign({}, variantsObject, newVariants));
  };

  console.log(variantsObject);

  const variants = [
    ['6gb', 'red'],
    ['4gb', 'red'],
  ];

  return (
    <table className="table-default variantTable" responsive>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Variant</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Sku</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        {variants.map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" className="vCBox" id={item.toString()} />
            </td>
            <td>{item.toString().split(',').join(' / ')}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="$0.00"
                name="variantPrice"
                onBlur={(e) => getPrice(e.target.value, item.toString())}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                name="variantQty"
                onBlur={(e) => getQty(e.target.value, item.toString())}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder=""
                name="variantSku"
                onBlur={(e) => getSku(e.target.value, item.toString())}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<VariantForm/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Working, Thanks

Comment: @KamaleshMaity I would appreciate to mark the response as accepted.

Comment: i have marked already

Comment: thank you but it doesn't have accepted mark, maybe you just have given it upvote.

Comment: oh sorry i dont know that thing i have marked now

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: one thing could you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240682/discussion-between-kamalesh-maity-and-saeed-shamloo).